# Which one is correct about bools.xml?

Tags: android

I find there are two ways to define bool var in bools.xml, which one is correct? Thanks!

```
----------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="screen_small">true</bool>
    <bool name="adjust_view_bounds">true</bool>
</resources>
-------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="bool" name="api11">false</item>
</resources>
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<bool>` make code shorter and cleaner, but both syntax is correct and work.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax for boolean would be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool
        name="bool_name"
        >[true | false]</bool>
</resources>
```

See : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html